# Definition of cells in a selected area

Tags: excel, cells, openoffice-calc, vba

I have the following VBA code to convert to OpenOffice Calc:

```
Sub RangeButton()
Dim rngArea As Range
    For Each rngArea In Selection.Areas
    Cells(3, 2).Value = rngArea(1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & rngArea(rngArea.Cells.Count).Address(0, 0)
    Next rngArea
End Sub
```

I'm creating a range button to define in a cell (3,2) the first and the last cell of a selected area. I would like to know how I can define the first and the last cell selected.

In VBA is defined like:

```
rngArea(1).Address(0, 0)
rngArea(rngArea.Cells.Count).Address(0, 0)
```

Comment: I couldn't say I understand your issue, but I think this will help you: `MsgBox (Replace(Range(Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column), Cells(Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.Count - 1, Selection.Column + Selection.Columns.Count - 1)).Address, "$", ""))`

Comment: Sorry. What I really want is a code for Open Office BASIC which allows the user to press a Button and save in a cell the selection he has just done with the mouse. For example: The user selects A2:C5 with the mouse and press the button, then, in the Cell("B3") the string "A2:C5" will appear. I need to do this because I will use this range as an input for another function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(rngArea(1).Address(0, 0),rngArea(rngArea.Cells.Count).Address(0, 0))
```

? (If *In VBA is defined like* means that you defined the first and the last cells).
I personally would define them as

```
Selection = Range( _  
Cells(rngArea(1).Row,rngArea(1).Column), _ 
Cells(rngArea(1).Row + rngArea(1).Rows.Count - 1, rngArea(1).Column + rngArea(1).Columns.Count - 1) _  
)
```